# Crypto.subtle in Dart?

Tags: typescript, flutter, dart, cryptography, subtlecrypto

Is there any package or utilities related to `crypto.subtle` present in Dart?
I found [this](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-html/Crypto/subtle.html) but I believe that's read-only, not accessible and for browsers only.

I am looking for something similar for this piece of code in dart

```js
 static async CbcEncrypt(data: Uint8Array, iv: Uint8Array, key: Uint8Array): Promise<Uint8Array> {
    const importedKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
      'raw',
      key,
      {
        //this is the algorithm options
        name: 'AES-CBC',
      },
      false, //whether the key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
      ['encrypt', 'decrypt'] //can be "encrypt", "decrypt", "wrapKey", or "unwrapKey"
    );

    const cipher = await crypto.subtle.encrypt(
      {
        name: 'AES-CBC',
        iv: iv,
      },
      importedKey, //from generateKey or importKey above
      data //ArrayBuffer of data you want to encrypt
    );

    return new Uint8Array(cipher);
  }
```

I looked at various packages [crypto](https://pub.dev/packages/crypto), [webcrypto](https://pub.dev/packages/webcrypto), [cryptography](https://pub.dev/packages/cryptography) but I couldn't relate anything to the code above.

I did find a package [pointycastle](https://pub.dev/packages/pointycastle) that looked promising. Is this thing could be a similar to `crypto.subtle` ??

Or
Is it possible to get access to the brower's crypto.subtle object / API from Dart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```dart
import 'package:webcrypto/webcrypto.dart';

Future<List<int>> cbcEncrypt(
  List<int> data,
  List<int> iv,
  List<int> key
) async {
  final key = await AesCbcSecretKey.importRawKey(key);
  final ciphertext = await key.encryptBytes(data, iv);
  return ciphertext;
}
```

But I'm also author of [`package:webcrypto`](https://pub.dev/packages/webcrypto) :D

There is no concept of `extractable` or `usages` in `package:webcrypto`. You can just wrap the object if you need to forbid such things (or maybe we'll add it in the future). There is also no wrap/unwrap/derive key support in `package:webcrypto`, but you can simply export a raw key and encrypt/decrypt or a do `deriveBits` and pass the derived bits to import raw key (this is the same that the `window.subtle` APIs do.

---

**Tip:** methods in `package:webcrypto` that returns bytes always return [`Uint8List`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-typed_data/Uint8List-class.html) which implements `List<int>`. You'll get slightly faster operations by only passing around `Uint8List`. But other APIs working with bytes in Dart pass around `List<int>`, so `package:webcrypto` accepts it as input.